# Removing a child node I have just appended in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I am very new to html and javascript. I am trying to validate a form. When a user does not enter a date in the correct format I want a paragraph to show below the input asking them to enter a valid date. I have managed to do this by appending child. However, I haven't been able to remove the child when a correct date is entered. I'm sure it is something really simple but have had no luck looking online. Also I am wondering if there is a way to only add the para if it does not already exist. Below is the code.

```
function checkDate(date) 
{       
    var result;
    var expression = /[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/;
    result = expression.test(date.value);
    var para=document.createElement("p");
    var node=document.createTextNode("Enter a valid Date");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element=document.getElementById(date.id).parentNode;

    if(!result===true)
    {   
        element.appendChild(para);  
    }

    else
    {

        element.removeChild(para);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to remove an element you just created. So if you call your function three times you will have three new elements.

One of the ways to solve this issue is to make a global reference to your element p. Like this:

```
para=document.createElement("p");

function checkDate(date) 
{       
    var result;
    var expression = /[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/;
    result = expression.test(date.value);

    var node=document.createTextNode("Enter a valid Date");
    para.appendChild(node);
    var element=document.getElementById(date.id).parentNode;

    if(!result===true)
    {   
        element.appendChild(para);  
    }

    else
    {

        element.removeChild(para);
    }       
}
```

This should work although I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to keep the para hidden and only show and hide according to your need, for example

```
<p id="para">Enter a valid Date</p>
```

To, show/hide you can use

```
document.getElementById('para').style.display = 'none'; // hide
document.getElementById('para').style.display = 'block'; // show
```

But, since you asked to remove the element so you can do it as

```
var para = document.getElementById('para');
para.parentNode.removeChild(para);
```

But, to do this, you have to add an `id` to the para whencreating it like

```
var para=document.createElement("p");
para.id = 'para';
```

[Node.removeChild on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.removeChild)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add an empty <span id="dateError"></span> and change content of it.

**But in your code:**

You are missing the most important attribute in HTML when you want to use JavaScript: **"id"**

You can identify each element using their ids. I've modified your code and it's working now. It's prevent possible duplicates too:

```
function checkDate(date) 
{       
var result;
var expression = /[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/;
result = expression.test(date.value);
var para=document.createElement("p");
var para.id = "dateError"; //NEW
var node=document.createTextNode("Enter a valid Date");
para.appendChild(node);
var element=document.getElementById(date.id).parentNode;

if(!result===true)
    {   
        if(document.getElementById("dateError") == null) return; //NEW
        element.appendChild(para);  
    }

    else
    {
        //element.removeChild(para);
        document.getElementById("dateError").remove(); //NEW
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your error `div` a unique id, based on the input id. Only recreate it if it doesn't already exist. This way you can have different error messages for each input.

```
function checkDate(date) 
{       
  var result;
  var expression = /[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/;

  result = expression.test(date.value);

  var errid = date.id + "-error";

  var para = document.getElementById(errid);
  var newp = false;

  if (! para) {
    newp = true;
    var para=document.createElement("p");
    para.id = errid;
    var node=document.createTextNode("Enter a valid Date");
    para.appendChild(node);
  }

  var element=document.getElementById(date.id).parentNode;

  if(!result===true)
    {   
      if (newp)
        element.appendChild(para);  
    }
    else
    {
      if (! newp)
        element.removeChild(para);
    }
}
```

working example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/HIDAC